# Cant parse simple json string (android)

Tags: java, php, android, json

Sorry for my English. I can't send json to server. My algorithm: user checks the image from gallery, then write all information about yourself(name, email), then click insert to server and add data is -> **first** load image and its return json string`{"status":"success","url":"\/files\/clients_photos\/tmp\/snapshot_tmp.jpg"}` i parsing this json string like this:

```
JsonObject jobj = new Gson().fromJson(imageUrl, JsonObject.class);
            myRes = jobj.get("url").getAsString();
```

and variable `myRes` post to server with all data json. I think this is error, but I can fix it. Below is my error:

```
   05-06 15:06:46.621: E/AndroidRuntime(21766): FATAL EXCEPTION: AsyncTask #1
        05-06 15:06:46.621: E/AndroidRuntime(21766): java.lang.RuntimeException: An error occured while executing doInBackground()
        05-06 15:06:46.621: E/AndroidRuntime(21766):    at android.os.AsyncTask$3.done(AsyncTask.java:278)
        05-06 15:06:46.621: E/AndroidRuntime(21766):    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerSetException(FutureTask.java:273)
        05-06 15:06:46.621: E/AndroidRuntime(21766):    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.setException(FutureTask.java:124)
        05-06 15:06:46.621: E/AndroidRuntime(21766):    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(FutureTask.java:307)
        05-06 15:06:46.621: E/AndroidRuntime(21766):    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:137)
        05-06 15:06:46.621: E/AndroidRuntime(21766):    at android.os.AsyncTask$SerialExecutor$1.run(AsyncTask.java:208)
        05-06 15:06:46.621: E/AndroidRuntime(21766):    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1076)
        05-06 15:06:46.621: E/AndroidRuntime(21766):    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:569)
        05-06 15:06:46.621: E/AndroidRuntime(21766):    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:856)
        05-06 15:06:46.621: E/AndroidRuntime(21766): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
        05-06 15:06:46.621: E/AndroidRuntime(21766):    at profile.Registration$GetPollsInformation.doInBackground(Registration.java:179)
        05-06 15:06:46.621: E/AndroidRuntime(21766):    at profile.Registration$GetPollsInformation.doInBackground(Registration.java:1)
        05-06 15:06:46.621: E/AndroidRuntime(21766):    at android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:264)
        05-06 15:06:46.621: E/AndroidRuntime(21766):    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(FutureTask.java:305)
        05-06 15:06:46.621: E/AndroidRuntime(21766):    ... 5 more

05-06 15:22:47.946: E/WindowManager(22921): Activity profile.Registration has leaked window com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView@419acd68 that was originally added here
05-06 15:22:47.946: E/WindowManager(22921): android.view.WindowLeaked: Activity profile.Registration has leaked window com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView@419acd68 that was originally added here
05-06 15:22:47.946: E/WindowManager(22921):     at android.view.ViewRootImpl.<init>(ViewRootImpl.java:363)
05-06 15:22:47.946: E/WindowManager(22921):     at android.view.WindowManagerImpl.addView(WindowManagerImpl.java:268)
05-06 15:22:47.946: E/WindowManager(22921):     at android.view.WindowManagerImpl.addView(WindowManagerImpl.java:216)
05-06 15:22:47.946: E/WindowManager(22921):     at android.view.WindowManagerImpl$CompatModeWrapper.addView(WindowManagerImpl.java:141)
05-06 15:22:47.946: E/WindowManager(22921):     at android.view.Window$LocalWindowManager.addView(Window.java:537)
05-06 15:22:47.946: E/WindowManager(22921):     at android.app.Dialog.show(Dialog.java:278)
05-06 15:22:47.946: E/WindowManager(22921):     at profile.Registration$GetPollsInformation.onPreExecute(Registration.java:146)
05-06 15:22:47.946: E/WindowManager(22921):     at android.os.AsyncTask.executeOnExecutor(AsyncTask.java:561)
05-06 15:22:47.946: E/WindowManager(22921):     at android.os.AsyncTask.execute(AsyncTask.java:511)
05-06 15:22:47.946: E/WindowManager(22921):     at profile.Registration$1.onClick(Registration.java:74)
05-06 15:22:47.946: E/WindowManager(22921):     at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:3517)
05-06 15:22:47.946: E/WindowManager(22921):     at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:14155)
05-06 15:22:47.946: E/WindowManager(22921):     at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:605)
05-06 15:22:47.946: E/WindowManager(22921):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
05-06 15:22:47.946: E/WindowManager(22921):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154)
05-06 15:22:47.946: E/WindowManager(22921):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4624)
05-06 15:22:47.946: E/WindowManager(22921):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
05-06 15:22:47.946: E/WindowManager(22921):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
05-06 15:22:47.946: E/WindowManager(22921):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:809)
05-06 15:22:47.946: E/WindowManager(22921):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:576)
05-06 15:22:47.946: E/WindowManager(22921):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

And its my code:

```
protected Void doInBackground(String... params) {

            //load image 
            SyncHttpClient client = new SyncHttpClient();
            RequestParams paramsImage = new RequestParams();
            try {
                paramsImage.put("photo", new File(filePath));

            } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

            client.post("http://crm.pavlun.info/api/upload_photo", paramsImage, new TextHttpResponseHandler() {
              @Override
              public void onFailure(int statusCode, Header[] headers, String responseString, Throwable throwable) {

              }

              @Override
              public void onSuccess(int statusCode, Header[] headers, String responseString) {
                  Log.e("responseString", ""+responseString);
                  imageUrl = responseString;

                  Log.e("imageURL", ""+imageUrl);
              }
            });

            //////////
            //maybe is this the error?

            JsonObject jobj = new Gson().fromJson(imageUrl, JsonObject.class);
            myRes = jobj.get("url").getAsString();

            Log.e("link gson", myRes); 

            /////////////////////////////////////////

            ArrayList<NameValuePair> nameValuePairs1 =  new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();

            JSONObject joB = new JSONObject();

            JSONArray list1 = new JSONArray();
            list1.add(params[0]);

            Map obj=new LinkedHashMap();
            obj.put("company_id","1");
            obj.put("phones", list1);
            obj.put("photo", myRes);
            obj.put("name",params[1]);
            obj.put("birthdate",params[2]);
            obj.put("email",params[3]);

            org.json.JSONObject jsonqwe;

            try {
                JSONParser operationLink = new JSONParser();
                ArrayList<NameValuePair> postP = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
                postP.add(new BasicNameValuePair("json", JSONValue.toJSONString(obj)));
                jsonqwe = operationLink.makeHttpRequest(registrationURL, "POST", postP);

                Log.e("sad", jsonqwe.toString());



            }catch(Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

            return null;
        }
```

Comment: I don't think imageUrl is set by the time you call new Gson().fromJson(imageUrl, JsonObject.class); Add a log there

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Gson pojo for parsing

```
public class RequestResponse {

private String status;
private String url;

//getter and setter goes here
}
```

Parsing response

```
RequestResponse data= new Gson().fromJson(imageUrl, RequestResponse.class);
String status=data.getStatus();
String url =data.getUrl();
```

Comment: As @Jaydipsinh Zala said put the code in `onSuccess` where you get your response.